# Methods to increase significance in regression

Tags: regression

What are the potential reasons why the relationships are insignificant in my regression model, and what can I do to increase significance?

Comment: This question is too vague to be answerable in its current form. Can you add more information about your model? You may want to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq). If the question cannot be specified to the point where it is answerable, it will need to be closed. Note also that there are a number of questions already on this site that explore reasons *in general* why reg models might be non-significant; you may want to search the site & read some of the existing answers as well.

Comment: since you are new I suggest you to explain about your question as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

As @gung said, your question is vague. However, in general, there are some things you could do:
1) Increase sample size. A larger sample with the same effect size will be more significant.

2) Measure things more accurately. Inaccurate measures add to error which makes it harder to find a relationship.

3) Get a better model. Maybe the reason your relationships are not significant is that your model is wrong. But without knowing anything about your model, it's hard to say.

Comment: It could be so many things.  Knowing the specifics of you problem, the variables in the model and the residuals would all help to make it possible to give specific advice.  (1) You could be choosing variables poorly. (2) the variable could be right but should be represented on a transformed scale (quadratic or log) (3) there is a missing variable that will work well at improving the model and (4) the model assumptions could br violated.

Comment: @PeterFlom, these general strategies certainly might work (+1), but I think it's worth noting that if someone fits a model, finds it non-significant, & then does some of these things & tests again, the p-value is no longer valid.

Comment: True @gung . I wonder how often, in published research, that rule is violated?  I would guess that it happens a lot! (Not that that makes it right)